# Page break via python-docx in MS Word docx file appears only at the end

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to add a page break to the middle of a document using the docx-python library.

It would appear that when adding a pagebreak, the page break is added to the end of the document. Is there a method to add a page break to a specific location?

This is my current code.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

demo='gm.docx'
document = Document(docx=demo)

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if 'PUB' in paragraph.text:
        document.add_page_break()

document.save('gm.docx')
```

Comment: I assume there is something wrong with your for loop. `document.add_page_break()` works for me and add the break at the appropriate location.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Breaks of their various forms appear at the `Run` level:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#run-objects

So something like this should do the trick:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if 'PUB' in paragraph.text:
        run = paragraph.add_run()
        run.add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
```