# Python-docx: identify a page break in paragraph

Tags: python, search, python-docx, page-break

I iterate over document by paragraphs, then I split each paragraph text into sentences by `.` (dot with space). I split paragraph text in sentences i*n order to do more effective text search* compare to search in a whole paragraph text.

Then the code searches error in each word of sentence, error being taken from error-correction db. I show below a simplified code:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    sentences = paragraph.text.split('. ') 
    for sentence in sentences:
        words=sentence.split(' ')
        for word in words:
            for error in error_dictionary:
                 if error in word:
                     # (A) make simple replacement
                     word = word.replace(error, correction, 1)
                     # (B) alternative replacement based on runs 
                     for run in paragraph.runs:
                         if error in run.text:
                               run.text = run.text.replace(error, correction, 1)
                         # here we may fetch page break attribute and knowing current number 
                         # find out at what page the replacement has taken place 
                         if run.page_break== WD_BREAK:
                              current_page_number +=1
                     replace_counter += 1
                     # write to a report what paragraph and what page
                     write_report(error, correction, sentence, current_page_number )  
                     # for that I need to know a page break
```

The problem is how to identify if a run (or other paragraph element) contains a page break? Does `run.page_break == WD_BREAK` work?
@scanny has showed [how to add page break](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655611/1230477), but how to **identify it**?

The best would be if one can identify also a **line break in paragraph**.

I could make:

```
for run in paragraph.runs:
    if run._element.br_lst:             
        for br in run._element.br_lst:
            br_couter+=1
            print br.type
```

Yet this code shows only **Hard breaks**, that is, breaks inserted thru *Ctrl+Enter*. **Soft page breaks** are not detected... (*Soft page break* is formed when user keeps typing until the page he is on runs out then it flows on to the next page)

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the **Soft** and **Hard** page breaks I now use the following:

```
for run in paragraph.runs:
    if 'lastRenderedPageBreak' in run._element.xml:  
        print 'soft page break found at run:', run.text[:20] 
    if 'w:br' in run._element.xml and 'type="page"' in run._element.xml:
        print 'hard page break found at run:', run.text[:20]
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: `python-docx` now includes the ability to locate rendered page-breaks. This is a good place to start: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html?highlight=page#docx.text.run.Run.contains_page_break

In general, a `RenderedPageBreak` object will occur in a `Run` and there is `Run.contains_page_break` to identify runs that have them and `Run.iter_inner_content()` to locate exactly where in the run they occur. There is also `Paragraph.contains_page_break` to identify them at the paragraph level and `Paragraph.rendered_page_breaks` to enumerate those if you don't need to know exactly where they occur.

---

There is no way to detect soft page breaks from a .docx file. The position of those is known only to the rendering engine and is not reflected in the .docx file itself. If you search here for '[python-docx] page break' or '[python-docx] TOC' you'll find a more elaborate explanation of this.

As to the first part of your question, this page from the technical analysis section of the `python-docx` documentation shows what breaks look like in the underlying XML:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/breaks.html#specimen-xml

There is no API support yet for explicitly finding breaks, although the `run.text` property indicates them with a `\n` line-feed character. The `\n` doesn't distinguish line breaks from page breaks however.

If you need to get more specific, you'll need to dig into the XML under each run and look for the specific break (`w:br`) elements you're interested in and their attributes:

```
>>> run._element.xml
<w:r>
  <w:t>Text before</w:t>
  <w:br/>
  <w:t>and after line break</w:t>
</w:r>
```

The `run._element.br_lst` approach you mention is a good one, then you just need to examine the attributes of each `w:br` to see if it has a `w:type=` attribute.

Comment: it ended up with me just splitting paragraph text in lines (and counting lines index) as the following: `for line in paragraph.text.splitlines()`

Comment: I'm creating a docx file with python-docx and have different paragraph line spacing (DOUBLE and SINGLE) at different points, so counting the lines doesn't really work, unless I were to determine the spacing type when calculating.  That's a lot of work.

Comment: As the last posting is from 2019, was wondering whether there have been any developments regarding the TOC topic?