# Python-docx: How can I remove last page from a word document

Tags: python, ms-word, ms-office, python-docx

I am trying to remove the last page from the word document, but haven't found any solution yet. More precisely I want to remove a section from a document.

```
document.sections[-1]
```

Can be used to access the last section, but how can I remove it.

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question. I presume you're using python-docx from the tag, but I don't see how you're trying to use it. Paste the entire code that you're trying to use.

Comment: `f = open(self.dir_path+"/app/"+template_file_name,'rb')
 document = docx.Document(self.dir_path+"/app/"+template_file_name) last_section=document.sections[-1]                                          document.save(report_name)`                                                                                           I have docx template, and I want to remove the last section/page from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the unfortunately short answer seems to be: you can't do this with python-docx, at least not with their API. If you dug down into the guts you could probably hack something out that would work for your specific case. But in the last 10-15 minutes of research I did this doesn't appear to be possible.

Here's a few issues:

1. Python-docx does not have notions of pages, see [Python-docx: identify a page break in paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084249/python-docx-identify-a-page-break-in-paragraph)
2. Copying content from one doc to another (or equivalently creating an empty doc and copying content to it) is quite complex and in general is not supported by python-docx. See [combine word document using python docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872527/combine-word-document-using-python-docx)

Though from the posts in (2) it seems there might be an alternative package that could help (https://pypi.org/project/docxcompose/).

**Edit:** This is as far as I got. It's quite kludgy but worked with a very quick basic test, though I think it's partially broken. And it left a blank page at the end. This definitely doesn't solve the question, but maybe could be a starting point to dig more.

```py
import docx

d = docx.Document('test.docx')
new_doc = docx.Document()

def get_last_page_break(document):
    paragraph_index = 0
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        paragraph_index += 1
        run_index = 0
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            run_index += 1
            if 'lastRenderedPageBreak' in run._element.xml: # soft page break
                lastpara_index = paragraph_index
                lastrun_index = run_index
            elif 'w:br' in run._element.xml and 'type="page"' in run._element.xml: # hard page break
                lastpara_index = paragraph_index
                lastrun_index = run_index
    return lastpara_index, lastrun_index

def kludgy_remove_last_page(document):
    new_doc = docx.Document()
    last_para, lastrun_index = get_last_page_break(d)

    for para in d.paragraphs[:last_para]:
        new_para = new_doc.add_paragraph()
        for run in para.runs[:lastrun_index]:
            new_para.add_run(run.text)
            if 'w:br' in run._element.xml and 'type="page"' in run._element.xml: # hard page break
                new_doc.add_page_break()
    return new_doc

new_doc = kludgy_remove_last_page(d)
new_doc.save('removed.docx')
```