# Python docx page break

Tags: python, python-docx

When you write something in docx file  and you are at the end of the page Microsoft world automatically render you to a new blank page .
is there any way you can know with python docx if you are in the new page.

Comment: have you checked in documentation? breaks should be available in runs in docx, see https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/breaks.html

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 types of page breaks in word documents, soft and hard.
Soft break are not not detectable and hard page break.

Here is a good post about it
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084249/python-docx-identify-a-page-break-in-paragraph#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20way%20to%20detect%20soft%20page,you%27ll%20find%20a%20more%20elaborate%20explanation%20of%20this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084249/python-docx-identify-a-page-break-in-paragraph#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20way%20to%20detect%20soft%20page,you%27ll%20find%20a%20more%20elaborate%20explanation%20of%20this).

Comment: This answer could probably be a comment, unless you cite the specific parts of the cited source that are relevant to the question (AND provide an attempt to answer the question)

Comment: Thanks for linking to the other SO question, Laurent. That question's accepted answer suggests that soft breaks are actually detectable, so I've submitted another answer based on your link. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, a docx paragraph consists of runs, and some of those runs are or contain a page break. (I don't know the data model, so I don't know whether 'some runs are' or 'some runs contain' is correct.)

This other answer on Stack Overflow says that [it is possible to detect whether a run is/contains a soft page break](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53337035/473899).

Hopefully you can use that to determine whether your text is before or after the soft page break. I hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note to the person who just edited this question: the SO guideline for removing polite phrases is ["Remove 'Hi' and 'Thank you' - but only while you're at it."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/473899). I don't mind you removing it. I hope you don't mind me putting it back.